# How to fit a piecewise regression in R, and constrain the first fit to pass through the intercept..?

Tags: r, regression, lm

I would like to perform a broken-stick regression in which the intercept of the first segment is constrained to pass through the origin.

The below code uses the 'segmented' package in R to fit two linear models to the data.

Notice though that the regression for the first segment does not pass through the origin - as far as I can tell, segmented does not allow the user to specify  that the intercept for the first segment should pass through the origin.

So, how would one perform such a broken-line regression, whilst constraining the first segment to pass through the origin..?

```
## create data with two 'growth' regimes
n <- 100
x <- 1:n
y1 <- x[1:(n/2)] + rnorm(n=n/2, mean = 0, sd=10) 
y2 <-              rnorm(n=n/2, mean = 0, sd=5) + max(y1)
y <- c(y1,y2)
DF <- data.frame(x,y )

## fit a broken-stick regression model 
library(segmented)
LM <- lm(y~x, DF)
Seggie <- segmented(LM, seg.Z=~x, npsi=1, psi=n/2)

## plot the data & the model
plot(Seggie); abline(h=0, lty=2); abline(v=0, lty=2)
points(y ~ x, DF); abline(h=0, lty=2)
```

[image: Broken_Stick]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice example.

You just need to adjust your formula so that it requires going through the origin.  You can do that by adding `+0` to your dependent variables. (See `?formula`)

```
LM <- lm(y~x+0, DF)
Seggie <- segmented(LM, seg.Z=~x+0, npsi=1, psi=n/2)
plot(Seggie)
abline(h=0, lty=2); abline(v=0, lty=2)
points(y ~ x, DF); abline(h=0, lty=2)
```

[image: Segmented model going through origin]